# What does "You are not in it for nothing" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> A: Is it the room?
> B: Of course!
> B: I will not be able to sleep in that landfill.
> A: The theater always sends the authors there.
> B: Authors?
> B: You would never let Vinaver or Yasmina Reza stay there.
> B: ***You are not in it for nothing.***
> B: I'm not here for my pleasure.
> B: I am invited, but I also have work to do.

What does "You are not in it for nothing" mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you not in it for nothing.
You are: In it for something.
Meaning: for some reason

Answer (score 0):

B is implying that A is making money from the situation.

To "be in it for nothing" means to do something without being paid or making a profit. To suggest that A is "not in it for nothing" suggests that A is corruptly profiting from giving B a low-quality room.